# Contactless measurement of internal time base

Tags: measurement, time

I'm currently trying to measure the internal time base of stopwatch (both mechanical and digital) to ascertain the expected accuracy of the device. I have looked through many articles related to the measurement of these devices, and I have come across 2 methods -  inductive and acoustics. My question is how do I implement these two methods to read on my frequency counter? The frequency counter has a minimum input of 60 mV pk-pk.

Edit: What I would really need to measure is the internal crystal oscillator of the device without opening any covers. I know you can measure the oscillator with a spectrum analyzer a bare piece of coaxial cable but you may need to be very close, and have such **expensive** equipment on hand. I measure a crystal  with values between 30 kHz and 5 MHz with just a frequency counter, without opening the device?

Comment: For a mechanical stopwatch, tape a small microphone onto the stopwatch and look at the output on a scope. This may work, or you may need to condition the mic output first.

Comment: If poking it open is an option, that's the easiest method. Just measure the oscillator directly with your scope. Takes like 10 minutes tops. Scope probe quality and sample rate might matter a little bit.

Comment: Though this is an interesting question, I'm voting to close it, because as currently written, the best answer that can be given is a general methodology; it won't be applicable in all cases, or to cover a broad enough range of cases, will be very long (and thus maybe not very useful to you). If you can provide some details of what it is you wish to measure, and some basic measurements (say of the electromagnetic field in and around the device, or a mic as suggested above), a more direct answer may become available.

Comment: I small mic would definitely work for mechanical stopwatches.